# Because of this

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm confused as to what "this" in "Because of this" refers to.
Is it referring to a single thing or multiple things?

I suppose it could refer to (1) Kali Yuga being used as an explanation for the state of the world, and/or (2) Kali Yuga aligning with the concept of acceleration, but I'm not sure if it refers to either one of them or both of them.
Thank you in advance.

> The world today is a dark one. Infrastructure is failing, wealth gaps
> increase, the environment degrades, politics is polarized to the point
> of crisis. The Kali Yuga is used by the schizo-scene as an
> explanation; a new millenarian age to bring justice to the world. A
> common and popular reaction to this idea regardless of ideological
> flavor is acceleration. To push through the contradictions of
> modernity and overcome them. **Because of this**, Kali Yuga has become
> a relevant narrative and aesthetic to most schizo-posters.
> Acceleration and collapse could be seen as one of, if not the most
> important shared narrative within the schizo-scene.
>
> https://legacy.donotresearch.net/posts/millenarian-dreams-of-the-schizo-scene/

Comment: IMHO, this text really is so much drivel, so I can't be bothered to check the *full* context to see whether the writer gives a clear definition of what he means by ***acceleration*** here. But syntactically, the "common and popular reaction" (to the idea that we're now living through "Kali Yuga") is "acceleration", and that's what causes Kali Yuga to be a relevant narrative today.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "because of this" here means "Because this is a common and popular reaction [so the narrative easily finds a natural home], …". What's really unclear to me is what "this idea" is in "A common and popular reaction to this idea…". I *think* it means "A common and popular reaction to the notion that the world is dark…".

The fragment before the one you put in bold isn't grammatically a sentence, by the way: it's phrased as one might talk in a speech, rather than as one might write. The entire quoted passage is confusing, unclear, and jumbled; and nothing is clarified in the original source you linked.

I believe the entire passage can be rephrased to the following:

> The world today is a dark one. Infrastructure is failing, wealth gaps increase, the environment degrades, politics is polarized to the point of crisis. A common and popular reaction on perceiving this state of affairs, regardless of one's original ideology, is acceleration: to push through and overcome the contradictions of modernity. The Kali Yuga narrative finds a natural home here: its aesthetic and story form a relevant explanation for the schizo-scene, providing a shared foundational narrative of acceleration, collapse, and a new millenarian age to bring justice to the world.

I still don't know what it means, though.

Answer (score 1):

'This' refers to "*a specific thing just mentioned*" (Oxford Dictionary).

True, there are quite a number of points mentioned prior to this statement, but one would have to assume it is either the point immediately prior to it *or* all of the previously mentioned points *as a whole*. It does seem like the text is describing a multi-faceted *situation*, and so I would argue for this latter possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Edited for content upon request.

The passage became clearer when I right-clicked on the  word **millenarian** which was unfamiliar to me and selected “Look up.”

**millenarian**: denoting a religious or political group seeking solutions to present crises through rapid and radical transformation of politics and society: *millenarian Marxists*.

Of the few definitions I sought to find a link for, this one remained the most relevant. It brought to mind the concept of the [Triad of Thesis, Antithesis, Synthesis](https://encyclopedia.pub/entry/32030).
From the link:
*In philosophy, the triad of thesis, antithesis, synthesis is a progression of three ideas or propositions. The first idea, the thesis, is a formal statement illustrating a point; it is followed by the second idea, the antithesis, that contradicts or negates the first; and lastly, the third idea, the synthesis, resolves the conflict between the thesis and antithesis.*

My reading of the original passage with minor tweaks for grammatical unity:
*The world today is a dark one. Infrastructure is failing; wealth gaps are increasing; the environment is degrading; all the while, politics are polarized to the point of crisis.*

*The Kali Yuga is used by the schizo-scene as an explanation (for manifesting) a new millenarian age to bring justice to the world.*

*A common and popular reaction to this idea, regardless of ideological flavor, is acceleration: to push through the contradictions of modernity and overcome them.*

*Because of this, Kali Yuga has become a relevant narrative and aesthetic to most schizo-posters. Acceleration toward collapse could be seen as one of, if not the most important shared narrative within the schizo-scene.*

Restated to substitute what I consider *this* to stand for:
Because *the idea that a new millenarian age can bring justice to a world in crisis transcends ideologies and is enthusiastically embraced by this population of posters*, then (the rest of the last paragraph).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. It really helped deepen my understanding of the passage. I'd also like to thank the other answerers for their valuable input.